# Converting socket.io data to JSON in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, socket.io

I'm writing a `socket.io` client and I'm having trouble getting the emitted data into any usable format.

My handler is:

```
socket.on("foriEvent") { data, ack in
    print(data)
}
```

which prints:

```
[  
   {  
      "foriEvent":{  
         "eventType":"location",
         "state":"moving",
         "latitude":"60.4413407",
         "longitude":"22.2476208",
         "accuracy":"20",
         "ts":1510653600189
      }
   }
]
```

I have a `Struct` that "looks" like that data, and I would like to use something like this where the from object is of type `Data`.

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let foriEvent = try decoder.decode(ForiEvent.self, from: data)
```

Currently I'm using the following to get a Data object, but when I send it to decoder.decode, I get the following error message:

```
return try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
```

> ```
> error trying to convert data to JSON typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, 
> Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription:
> "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found an array instead.", underlyingError: nil))
> ```

Could it be my struct? What should it look like? The `Struct` looks like this right now:

```
struct ForiEvent : Codable {
    var eventType: String?
    var state : String?
    var latitude: String?
    var longitude : String?
    var accuracy : String?
    var timeStamp : CLong?
}

struct ForiData : Codable {
    var foriEvent : ForiEvent?
}
```

Comment: I suggest you take a look at 3th party framework for JSON that SwiftyJson on github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use swiftyjson for this. It does a great job.

You haven't defined what type the data is but if it is a string which it looks like it is from the print command that you have then you can do this.

```
    guard let dataFromString = data[0].data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) else {return}
    var swiftyJson:JSON!
    do {
        swiftyJson = try JSON(data: dataFromString)
    } catch {
        print("Error JSON: \(error)")
    }
```

This will give you the data in JSON format which you can very easily parse using swiftyjson into the custom type you have outlined above. The reason that Codable might not be working is because your JSON is returned as an array of JSON.

Try this

```
let tempVar = swiftyJson["foriEvent"]["eventType"].string
print("test \(tempVar)")
```

Comment: Hi! Unfortunately I didn't get that working. I have no idea what "text" is supposed to be. A string, maybe, but if so, I can't seem to get the socket.io data cast to anything useful.

Comment: try that. I just changed text to data. In this piece of code, what type is data? NSData or String? `socket.on("foriEvent") { data, ack in
    print(data)
}`

Comment: also are you using swiftyjson?

Comment: Yes, I'm using swiftyjson. I don't actually know what the type of the data is that soclet.io emits. I don't have the server documentation, and this is more or less my first Swift program, so there's quite a lot I don't know :-/

Comment: ok no problem. Xcode makes it pretty easy to check that. if you hover over the word data and hold down alt/option on your keyboard and click the word data, it will tell you what type it is. I also prefer to use Starscream to connect to the web socket. I would give that a try as well.

Comment: can you also try changing "data" in your code here: `let foriEvent = try decoder.decode(ForiEvent.self, from: data)` to `let foriEvent = try decoder.decode(ForiEvent.self, from: data[0])`

Comment: I just made an edit to my code above can you try using that new code to see if it works?

Comment: As I know that there is no need to convert data (returned in on completion handler) in `JSONSerialization`, because it's already a dictionary of `Any` ([Any]).

Comment: With this change 

let foriEvent = try decoder.decode(ForiEvent.self, from: data[0] as! Data)

I get

Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x111a4bf68) to 'NSData' (0x111a4bdb0).

Comment: perfect so that means that it is of type string. Where are you getting this error? on what line?

Comment: Apparently this works: var swiftyJson = JSON((data[0] as! String).data(using : String.Encoding.utf8)!) so I think we're getting there :) so thanks a lot so far!

Comment: Yes! That should do it. Now do you know how to convert the JSON to the struct that you have created?

Comment: Yep. I've got everything working now: after having created the json from the string, this code extracts the struct contents: let jsonData = json["foriEvent"]
        do {
            self.data = try JSONDecoder().decode(ForiEventStruct.self, from: jsonData.rawData())

Comment: Awesome! If this was helpful then accept my answer. It might help others.

Comment: Yes, will do! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no need to implement any third party (BTW I'm not againsed to SwiftyJson or any other). 
You can do it as:

```
//Here is the new struct for your ForiEvent
struct ForiEvent {
var eventType: String?
var state : String?
var latitude: String?
var longitude : String?
var accuracy : String?
var timeStamp : CLong?

init(dict: [String:Any]) {
    if let obj = dict["eventType"] {
        eventType = "\(obj)"
    }

    if let obj = dict["state"] {
        state = "\(obj)"
    }

    if let obj = dict["latitude"] {
        latitude = "\(obj)"
    }

    if let obj = dict["longitude"] {
        longitude = "\(obj)"
    }

    if let obj = dict["accuracy"] {
        accuracy = "\(obj)"
    }

    if let obj = dict["timeStamp"] as? CLong {
        timeStamp = obj
    }
}
}

//You data as [[String:Any]] returend from on complitionhandler
let dictArray:[[String:Any]] = [[
"foriEvent":[
    "eventType" : "location",
    "state":"moving",
    "latitude":"60.4413407",
    "longitude":"22.2476208",
    "accuracy":"20",
    "ts":1510653600189
]
]
]

print(dictArray)


// How to Use it:
var foriEventArray = [ForiEvent]()
for eventData in dictArray {
if let eventDict = eventData["foriEvent"] as? [String:Any] {
    foriEventArray.append(ForiEvent(dict: eventDict))
}
}
print(foriEventArray)
```

Comment: That code works as copied/pasted, so I have faith in the struct itself. However, I still haven't been able to cast the data that the socket.io emits. With the line let dict = data[0] as! [String : Any] I get the error message Could not cast value of type '__NSCFString' (0x109b50f68) to 'NSDictionary' (0x109b51f58).

Answer (score 1):

Using SwiftyJSON is easiest way to handle json

Use this example

```
socket.on("foriEvent") { data, ack in
   // because 'data' is type of [Any] so we can use 'JSON.init(AnyObject)'
   let json:JSON = JSON(data[0])//JSON.init(parseJSON: cur)
    // variable json is ready for use as this json["foriEvent"]
}
```